# How to integrate facebook-passport in react app with express api?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, passport.js, passport-facebook

I created express api server, which runs on localhost:5000 with react app running on localhost:3000. Now I'm trying to integrate facebook authentication.

I followed [Scotch's tutorial about authenticatation using passport](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-facebook) in order to integrate facebook authentication in my own app. I have cloned his [repo](https://github.com/scotch-io/easy-node-authentication/tree/facebook), set up facebook login on [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) and it works correctly. Using his example I've tried to set up this flow in my app, but with no success. In firefox console I noticed one diffreance - when I click "login with facebook" in scotch's app, there are 3 requests:

1. http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook
2. https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback&scope=public_profile,email&client_id=CLIENT_ID
3. http://localhost:8080/auth/facebook/callback?code=A_LOT_OF_CHARS

In my app:

1. http://localhost:5000/auth/facebook
2. https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/api/oauth/facebook/callback&scope=public_profile,email&client_id=CLIENT_ID
3. [https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fapi%2Foauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback#*=*](https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fapi%2Foauth%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback#_=_)

So there is a difference in third request - Scotch is redirect to his callback, but in my app I got a link to message

> The parameter app_id is required

on facebook page.

How should I configure react to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have redirect route in your express app yet? Something like this.

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    // Successful authentication, redirect home.
    res.redirect('/');
 });
```

You can read the documentation here https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook#readme if you are still stuck. Hope it helps

Comment: Yes, I have. Later I have added simple html page with a link to "/api/oauth/facebook" which works correctly, so the problem is with react app

Comment: Do you create the app at (https://developers.facebook.com/apps?)? If yes, can you check your app_id matches your clientId in passport?

Comment: Yes and everything in passport is ok. As I mentioned in previous comment, the problem lies on the client side